# Performing SQL Query on a different date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have database which was used to be an Access database. Now, I have migrated to MySQL. There is a table 'installments' having lot of records and date is in a format like 'YYYY-mm-dd'.

Now I am storing new dates in a format like 'dd-mm-YYYY' by simply using date('d-m-Y') in PHP.

Now, I want to perform this query

```
SELECT * FROM `installments` WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

But it only works on older format, that is like 2016-07-12. It does work on 12-07-2016. What should I do now?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I know I can change the format by using date('Y-m-d') but I don't wanna do that.

Comment: are you storing the date in a proper date field, or in a text field? If you store it as a date, the format shouldn't matter

Comment: I am storing it in text field

Comment: I see you got an answer that works, but if you were doing this again i would use a proper date field in MySQL. That way, you don't have to store and retrieve it in any particular format. You just store it as a date object, and you only worry about what format it's in at the point you want to display it to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `installments` WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%m-%Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `installments` WHERE YEAR(TO_DATE(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(TO_DATE(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);
```

Hope this helps.